# Error in reaver 1.4 please help

Tags: wireless

After scanning for networks, I select one, then use the command

```
Reaver -i (device) -b (BSSID)
```

Then it says

> Waiting for bescons fron (BSSID)

And after that it says

> FAILED TO ASSOCIATE WITH (BSSID)

Yesterday this worked just fine, but today I'm getting that error.
Any idea how I can fix this?